# BitLocker doesn't recognize my password

Tags: windows-10, login, bitlocker

When I try to login on my Windows 10 BitLocker sometimes (quite often actually) doesn't recognize my password. In this case I have to go through the cumbersome recovery... I'm sure the password is okay (of course checked it after I pressed Insert). How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: You can try changing the password then creating a new recovery key.  BitLocker has not changed functionally in several versions of Windows.  *So its unlikely to be a bug.*

Comment: All but certainly, you are mistyping your password. Perhaps you have caps-lock on? Perhaps you are transposing characters?

Comment: I'll try creating a new recovery key... @ChrisInEdmonton: I know this seems very obvious but when you press Insert I can see my PW in plain text; I also tried using the F-keys, the numbers and the number-block... no luck. But as I said, this is not always the case. I too believe it's not a BitLocker bug but rather some issue of my PC...